# Azure Cognitive Search: Join types

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Elasticsearch has [Join field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html)

Solr has [Join query parser](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/join-query-parser.html)

What is the equivalent in Azure Cognitive Search? (if any)

The closest concept I've been able to find is [Complex Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types?tabs=portal), but they're more like the equivalent of "nested documents" in the other two technologies.  They don't allow for individual management of child records.  Instead they require that all children are [written together](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types?tabs=portal#data-updates) (which doesn't work for a large number of child records).